# undefined symbols when I use TCP's function in RL_ARM

Tags: c, embedded, arm

Like the title,my IDE is keil.In my program ,i add some functions in lt like below:

```
tcp_get_socket(Type,0,120,func);
tcp_connect(socket, remip, remport, locport);
tcp_close(socket);
tcp_send(sock, buf, len);
```

After compiling them ,the linker told me some error:

```
Error: L6218E: Undefined symbol tcp_socket (referred from at_tcp.o).
Error: L6218E: Undefined symbol tcp_NumSocks (referred from at_tcp.o).
Error: L6218E: Undefined symbol tcp_InitRetryTout (referred from at_tcp.o).
Error: L6218E: Undefined symbol tcp_2MSSTout (referred from at_tcp.o).
.
.
.
```

I want to know what is going on here.Any guy can tell me ?
If you want details,I will tell you.

Comment: Did you add the libraries? http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/rlarm/rlarm_tn_libfiles.htm

Comment: now I have TCP_ARM_L.lib and TCPD_ARM_L.lib.which else libs do I need to add into my project?

Comment: Are you targeting for ARM7 or ARM9? You shouldn't pick both release and debug libs, just one.

Comment: what i use is  NXP LPC2368 chip based on ARM7

Comment: Do you still get the same link errors?

Comment: If you still get same link errors then I don't know, but if it is different errors now that means you have a problem with your project setup.

Comment: yes,i think so.i will try again.Thank you!

Comment: How do I add these libs into my project??

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that I didn't enable TCP functionality in Net_Config.c .
So just enable it.